# Oracle grand total column and row

Tags: oracle, sum, row

I have this table as a result from another query

```
STATUS          R1  R2  R3  R4  R5  R6  R7  R8  R9
----------------------------------------------------
ACCEPTED        322 241 278 473 575 595 567 449 605
ADECUACIONES    0   0   0   0   2   0   1   0   50
AET             0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   11
EXECUTED        0   80  1   18  9   57  34  30  20
IN PROCESS      0   0   0   0   0   4   25  2   112
FREQ            0   55  2   76  25  117 7   73  48
INSTALL         1   4   1   10  5   14  2   13  62
WO INSTALL      9   2   51  24  143 17  15  59  16
WOT VL          0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
OTHER          22   7   20  28  44  30  6   6   109
PROG            1   0   1   0   0   2   3   0   0
PTE PROG        0   5   0   0   0   0   3   19  93
TMX             0   0   0   28  4   8   11  3   14
PROJ            0   1   12  26  13  8   0   2   4
```

What I expect to have is this

```
STATUS          R1  R2  R3  R4  R5  R6  R7  R8  R9  TOTAL
----------------------------------------------------------
ACCEPTED        322 241 278 473 575 595 567 449 605 4105
ADECUACIONES    0   0   0   0   2   0   1   0   50  53
AET             0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   11  13
EXECUTED        0   80  1   18  9   57  34  30  20  249
IN PROCESS      0   0   0   0   0   4   25  2   112 143
FREQ            0   55  2   76  25  117 7   73  48  403
INSTALL         1   4   1   10  5   14  2   13  62  112
WO INSTALL      9   2   51  24  143 17  15  59  16  336
WOT VL          0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   2
OTHER          22   7   20  28  44  30  6   6   109 272
PROG            1   0   1   0   0   2   3   0   0   7
PTE PROG        0   5   0   0   0   0   3   19  93  120
TMX             0   0   0   28  4   8   11  3   14  68
PROJ            0   1   12  26  13  8   0   2   4   66
TOTAL           355 396 368 683 821 852 674 656 1144 5949
```

I've been playing with `grouping()` and `rollup()`, but I always get duplicated rows and unwanted null values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have problems, grouping_id function will help you.

(You can select grouping_id(col), but also grouping_id(col1, col2, col3, etc..))

But your case is simpler.

It is like:

```
drop table fg_test_group;
create table fg_test_group (a number, b number, c number, d number);

insert into fg_test_group values (1, 2, 3, 4);
insert into fg_test_group values (2, 2, 3, 4);
insert into fg_test_group values (3, 2, 3, 4);


select  nvl(to_char(a), 'total') as a , sum(b), sum(c), sum(d), grouping_id(a)
from fg_test_group
group by rollup (a) 
;
```

where a is Status in your case.

Comment: Thanks, your answer pointed me in the right direction. I have the desired result. Thank you again!!

Comment: wht about the row wise total

Comment: @Lijo, Hi, it's interesting what you asked and not too simple, I think it's best to raise a question with oracle tag. (If someone didn't asked this until now)

Answer (score 4):

```
CREATE TABLE TEST1 (STATUS  VARCHAR2(10), R1 NUMBER, R2 NUMBER, R3 NUMBER);
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES ('ACCEPTED', 322,241,278);
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES ('EXECUTED', 0, 80, 1);
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES ('FREQ', 0, 55, 2);
COMMIT;


select  NVL(TO_CHAR(STATUS), 'total') as STATUS ,SUM(R1) R1, SUM(R2) R2 , SUM(R3) R3, SUM(R1+R2+R3)
from TEST1
group by rollup (STATUS) 
;


STATUS          R1  R2  R3  SUM(R1+R2+R3)

ACCEPTED        322 241 278 841

EXECUTED        0   80  1   81

FREQ            0   55  2   57

total           322 376 281 979
```